# Issue with Html5shiv and GWT

Tags: html, gwt

I have ported a project to gwt. I use UiBinder and  html5 tags all
around the place: , , ... things like that.
Things I have used before and that I have been able to render properly
in IE using html5shiv. However if I use html5shiv with gwt nothing is
rendered in IE. Is there any workaround for this or I'll have to
redesign the whole thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in GWT. Can you add the a UiBinder XML Code to the Post.

Please try adding the following to your module

```
<define-property name="user.agent" values="ie6">
```

Also please check developer tools console in IE for any errors.